# What can happen if Kafka lose partitions sync

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm facing a problem in work. We have a Kafka that runs on HDP cluster. It's been some days that Kafka lost partitions sync and I seem to lose some messages. Can someone confirm to me that if Kafka loses partitions sync it may lose messages?

Answer (score 0):

All messages are written to a leader partition only. If you have `acks=1` in a producer config, then you are guaranteed that the message was written to that leader.

If you also have `unclean.leader.election=false` on each broker in the cluster, then no out-of-sync replica can be elected leader, therefore will not accept writes and cause other followers to truncate their logs to match an unclean leader.

If neither of these conditions hold, you're liable for dropped messages.

---

Until recent releases of Kafka, there were still edge cases around the leader election and log truncation, which was discussed at Kafka Summit 2018 - [Hardening Kafka Replication](https://www.confluent.io/kafka-summit-sf18/hardening-kafka-replication)

You might also want to check out [Cloudera FAQ to see how to configure Kafka to store data reliably](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/6.0/topics/kafka_faq.html#concept_g5s_tpl_d2b__section_l5s_tpl_d2b)

But, want to point out highlight there

> Kafka **does not ensure** that data loss never occurs